# How to output 3 top sales for each customer using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have 3 simple tables like this:

**Customers table**

| customer_id | customer_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Gigashots |
| 2 | Devshare |
| 3 | Realblab |
| ... | ... |

**Products table**

| product_id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Omeprazole |
| 2 | ESZOPICLONE |
| 3 | Calcipotriene |
| ... | ... |

**Sales table**

| sale_date | customer_id | product_id | total_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-02-12 | 1 | 1 | 45651.68 |
| 2016-01-14 | 2 | 3 | 19139.20 |
| 2016-04-28 | 5 | 4 | 40195.22 |
| 2016-05-22 | 3 | 3 | 33808.53 |
| 2016-05-27 | 8 | 2 | 11880.73 |
| 2016-07-13 | 4 | 4 | 13092.21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**I need to select 'customer_name', 'product_name' and 'total_sum' and output 3 products for each customer on which he spent most of money in 2016**, sorted by:
customer_name - ascending;
total_sum - descending.

I tried to do it using this query:

```
SELECT
customer_name, product_name, total_sum
FROM sales
JOIN customer
ON customer.customer_id = sales.customer_id
JOIN product
ON product.product_id = sales.product_id
WHERE sale_date >= '2016-01-01' AND sale_date < '2017-01-01'
ORDER BY customer_name ASC, total_sum DESC
LIMIT 3
```

BUT the 'LIMIT 3' only shows me this:

| customer_name | product_name | total_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gigashots | Omeprazole | 37047.59 |
| Gigashots | ESZOPICLONE | 20114.64 |
| Gigashots | Calcipotriene | 19386.09 |

I know only the basics of SQL and can't get my head around this task. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use window functions along with aggregation:

```
SELECT cp.*
FROM (SELECT c.customer_name, p.product_name, SUM(s.total_sum) as total_sum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer_id ORDER BY SUM(s.total_sum) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales s JOIN
           customer c
           ON c.customer_id = s.customer_id JOIN
           product p
           ON p.product_id = s.product_id
      WHERE sale_date >= '2016-01-01' AND sale_date < '2017-01-01'
      GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.customer_name, p.product_id, p.product_name
     ) cp
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: Thank you, but somehow it shows an error at "product p JOIN" line saying "product is not valid at this position, expectin FOR, LOCK, SELECT etc."

Comment: @ВладимирЯшин . . . That was a typo.  The `JOIN` belonged on the previous line.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Although i don't quiet understand how second and third line work...

Comment: @ВладимирЯшин . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html.